# Can't connect to local database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

Today I created a local database on my computer. 
Then I installed SQL Developer. But I can't connect.

It gives me this error:

> "Status : Failure -Test failed: Locale not recognized"

[image: Here's my settings]

My database version: 11.2.0.1.0

Now I have only one  instance (2 databases deleted before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Oracle Support Community](https://community.oracle.com/message/1683313#1683313) this is likely due to a JDBC / Oracle JDBC driver issue; are you using an unusual Locale on your PC?  Is the ojdbc*.jar file on your PC that SQL*Developer is using the correct version for your database?

Comment: Thank you for reply, 
I resolved this issue. Solution was my OS regional & language settings. My settings was on Mongolia. And i changed it to English (United States). 

But i don't know  what relation my OS regional settings and JDBC driver each other.

Comment: From the link in my answer, apparently the JDBC driver has a built-in table of Locales that Oracle supports, and Mongolia appears to **not** be one of them.

Comment: If my answer lead you to changing your OS regional settings, can you mark this answer as accepted?  Thanks!